# Can i run visual studio and SQL Server for ASP.NET inside a virtual machine in Linux Mint 17.2?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint, visual-studio-2012, asp.net

I have linux mint 17.2 and windows 7 on my dell inspion n5050 laptop.As , I am a linux enthusiastic I love linux mint very much. Currently, windows 7 is occupying 167GB, linux mint is of 167GB, another drive of 167 GB and RAM of 4GB. I planned to format everything and install linux mint as a single os, but windows 7 in vmware. My question is that will the performance of windows 7 be same as dual boot if i install it inside vmware with filesystem size of 167GB(same as dual boot) and RAM of 2GB? Note that i just want to run Visual Studio and SQL Server for ASP.NET development inside windows 7

Answer (score 0):

It will not be the same performance-wise as a dual boot but it won't be terrible. You should look at the memory though.

Giving a Windows VM only 2GB of RAM will probably be what makes a noticeable performance hit that you will see. If you can give it 4GB or so when you are actively using Visual Studio, your dev experience will be much better. This is especially true since you mentioned running Visual Studio and SQL in the VM.

I actually do this on OS X all the time. I have 16GB of RAM, though, so I can give the VM a lot.